# Why does this program create an error?

Tags: haskell, types

I was trying out Haskell and did this:

```
data Point  = Point Float Float            deriving (Show)
data Vector = Vector Float Float           deriving (Show)
data Line   = Line Point Point             deriving (Show)
data Rect   = Rect Point Point             deriving (Show)
data QGon   = QGon Point Point Point Point deriving (Show)
data Circle = Circle Point Float           deriving (Show)

makeList (Point x y)        = [ x, y ]
makeList (Vector x y)       = [ x, y ]
makeList (Line p1 p2)       = [ makeList p1, makeList p2 ]
makeList (Rect p1 p2)       = [ makeList p1, makeList p2 ]
makeList (QGon p1 p2 p3 p4) = [ makeList p1, makeList p2
                              , makeList p3, makeList p4 ]
```

It produced an error saying that:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Float]’ with ‘Float’
    Expected type: Point -> Float
      Actual type: Point -> [Float]
  |
8 | makeList (Point x y)  = [ x, y ]
```

Unfortunately, I can't get hold of the meaning of this.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are floats then `[x,y]` is a list of floats.  The function `makeList` must have a result type of `[Float]`  but wait, there's more!  Another definition of `makeList` results in `[makeList p1, makelist p2]` so now makelist must have a result type of `[[Float]]` (and this reasoning can grow till we end up with an infinite nesting of lists). Which is correct?

Comment: Why do you need to reduce your well-defined shapes to generic lists in the first place? Your current attempt, for example, loses the distinction between a rectangle and a line.

Comment: Note that `makeList` can not be assigned any type -- it is a function taking arguments of different types. You should reconsider your design. It is usually better to write the intended type before writing the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `makeList` has different types for the cases:

- `makeList (Point x y)` has type `[Float]`
- `makeList (Line p1 p2)` has type `[[Float]]`

You may want to use `concat` to convert a list of list into a simple list.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. If that's intentional, you should reference that fact and explain why, and if not, well, try implementing your fix and check with GHC that it actually works.

Comment: More usefully, a `Point` and a `Vector` should probably be represented as singleton lists to be consistent with the other values. `makeList (Point x y) = [[x,y]]`.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime, I've gotten around it with makeList x = map read (drop 1 (words (show x)))

Comment: waaaaaaaaaaaaat